# Spivak's proof of change of variable theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

In proof of change of variable theorem Spivak, on page 69 writes $$\int_A [(f\circ h )\circ g][|\text {det} \ h'| \circ g]|\text {det} \ g'|=\int_A [f\circ (h \circ g)]|\text {det} \ (h\circ g)'|$$
How did we get this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have $(f\circ h )\circ g=f\circ (h \circ g)$, since composition of functions is associative. Next, by the chain rule
$$
(h\circ g)'=(h'\circ g)\,g'.
$$
Then
$$
\operatorname{det}\bigl((h'\circ g)\,g'\bigr)=\operatorname{det}\bigl((h'\circ g)\bigr)\,\operatorname{det}(g')=\bigl(\operatorname{det}(h')\circ g\bigr)\,\operatorname{det}(g')
$$